# php print 10 results of an array

Tags: php, arrays, rows

i have a question for you guys.
im trying to print an array where it would display 10 values of the table acording to user.
this is what i have so far and it displays only the first row,

```
session_start(); 
// Retrieve all the data from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,location,login_id FROM table WHERE login_id = $user[login_id]")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

echo " name  ".$row['name'];
echo " located  ".$row['location'];
```

.....
how can i display the first 10 rows?
help would be apreciated.
thank you for reading.

Comment: in fact, your array contains only **one** result

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: How do you know?

Comment: I wonder when someone will notice first 10 results condition (and post proper solution)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Ah I think I got now how you meant it... but I think the OP already knows that `$row` only contains one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start(); 
// Retrieve all the data from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,location,login_id FROM table WHERE login_id = $user[login_id] LIMIT 10")
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
    echo " name  ".$row['name'];
    echo " located  ".$row['location'];
}
```

And This will work only if your login_id is not unique and multiple rows can have the same login_id

Comment: yes they do login id is the identifier for the name. Beautiful. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

also add "limit 10" to the query.

```
SELECT name,location,login_id FROM table WHERE login_id = $user[login_id] LIMIT 10
```

Comment: limit is not working for some reaon i still get only the first row printed out.

Comment: @Homie it does, silly. But with PROPER code which you fail to write. Use Felix's code with this query. Start using your brains at last.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `mysql_fetch_array` repeatedly to get all the row from the result set:

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))) {
    echo " name  ".$row['name'];
    echo " located  ".$row['location'];
}
```

[See further examples in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

If you really want to get only the first 10 rows, have a look at [@Yasser Souri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991282/php-print-10-results-of-an-array/4991329#4991329) (you still have to loop though).

Comment: this answer is giving me results however it is still printing only the first row of the results. i need 5 to 10 rows printed.

Comment: @Homie: Are you sure then that your query returns more than one row? What does `mysql_num_rows($result)` give you? If there are more than one row in the result set, this will definitely print them all.

Comment: @Homie: So what was the problem now?